# reading table row but each <td> separately?

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<div id='c1'>
</div>

function()
{
$('#c1').append('<table ><tr><td id=v>'abc'</td> <td>'12'</td><td>'1'</td> <td>77 </td><td><span class=c>X</span></td></tr></table>');
}
function test()
    {
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    var s=document.getElementById('c1').getElementsByTagName('tr','td')[i].innerHTML;//
      this line give output =abc 121 77
    var t=document.getElementById('v')[i].innerHTML;//not working
    alert(t);
     //this t is setting in session using ajax
     }
```

I want to get `<tr>`data but each `<td>` separately.Is it possible to take each `<td>` data separately?
while getting it from session,got it as (abc 121 77 X) on another page how could i retrieve it each `<td>` as separate in java?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery "each" function ([link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)).

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var tr=[];

    $('tr').each(function() {
        var td=[];            
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){
          td.push($(this).text());
        });
        tr.push(td);            
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cthdn/